# Escape variable #id friendly with Smarty

Tags: html, internationalization, smarty, diacritics, lowercase

For a project with Smarty, I want to use a title variable for an ID in HTML. The variable should be lowercase, shouldn't have whitespaces and vowel mutations (ä, ö, ü, é, è, à, ...). 
For example `Übergrösse` should be `ubergrosse`.

After a major search I can't find a really useful command. So I tried it with `|replace` modifier, like this:

```
<section id="{$title|lower|replace:' ':''|replace:'ä':'a'|replace:'ö':'o'|replace:'ü':'u'|replace:'é':'e'|replace:'è':'e'|replace:'à':'a'}">...</section>
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to clean text to generate safe urls, so it would probably work for what you need:

```
function smarty_modifier_safetext($string){
    $string = preg_replace("`\[.*\]`U","",$string);
    $string = preg_replace('`&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;`i','-',$string);
    $string = preg_replace( '`"`i', "", $string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    $string = preg_replace( "`&([a-z])(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig|quot|rsquo);`i","\\1", $string );
    $string = html_entity_decode($string);
    $string = preg_replace( array("`[^a-z0-9]`i","`[-]+`") , "-", $string);
    return strtolower(trim($string, '-'));
}
```

Save this code as modifier.safetext.php in your smarty plugins folder and then use it just like this:

```
{$title|safetext}
```